# Git: edit a commit with interactive rebase

Tags: git

I'm trying to edit a specific old commit, basically un-commit some changes that were made to a few files in that commit.
I'm using:

```
git rebase --interactice 'fghj554^'
```

And then selects `'edit'` for that commit. However I'm being taken to the stage where those changes are already present in the files, and typing "git status" will show there's nothing to commit.

Is there a way to unstage the comitted files, so that I can use `git restore` for example, and not commit some changes to some files?

Comment: Change the files and `git add` them.  Then `git rebase --continue`

Comment: I want to discard some changes that were made in that commit. The correct way to do it would be to overwrite them with the old state of things? In simple terms I want to undo some of the commit, but not delete it entirely

Comment: @WilliamPursell given that it's an `edit`, it has to be `git add; git commit --amend --no-edit; git rebase --continue`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's how it's supposed to work.... so now, if you want to revert some changes, just run `git checkout HEAD~ -- file1 file2` (notice the pig tail) so that you can get those files to the way they ware before... *or* use your IDE to compare with the previous commit (though it could be other commits)... and then get the files the way you want. When you are done:

```
git add file1 file2 blahblah
git commit --amend
git rebase --continue
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, just a question please - when you "get those files to the way they were before", the changes that were made in that current commit will appear as unstaged files that I can then add and commit again? Or that checking out HEAD~ will discard the changes and in this commit and they will be gone?

Comment: "Pig tail" ...I'll reuse that :-D

Comment: @RomainValeri yes.... _tilde_ I think is too dry whereas pig tail is more graphical in nature.... hard to forget. In spanish: _"rabo'e cochino"_ or _"rabo'e chancho"_. :-D

Comment: The commit won't be modified until you `git commit --amend` it so feel free to play around.

Comment: I'll try that in a sandbox thanks for your help!

Comment: You can also use `git reset -p HEAD^ -- file1 file2` to get the patch-mode reset operation applied with the specified files. I personally don't like the patch-mode add and reset very much, I'd rather `git show HEAD~:file1 > file1.old` and open both files in the editor myself, but everyone has favorites...